# MGSplitViewController change detail view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

Using MGSplitViewController, how do I change the detail view controller?
There's a property declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *detailViewController; // convenience.
```

doing `splitVC.detailViewController = myVC;` has not effect. Instead I have to do `splitVC.viewControllers = @[masterVC, myVC];`.
It works, but is this the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right. From [UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) Reference:

> The split **view controller has no significant interface of its own**. Its
>   job is to manage the presentation of its two child view controllers
>   and transitions between different orientations.

also:

> You must assign two view controllers to a split view controller.
>   Usually you configure these view controllers in a storyboard; if you
>   create a split view controller programmatically, **you assign them using
>   the viewControllers property**.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to confirm :). Kinda confusing because the property is declared as retain, rather than readonly

Answer (score 1):

When using [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController), a way to set the `detailViewController` without resetting everything (which seems very inefficient) is to set the `detailViewController` and then call `layoutSubviews`

```
splitViewController.detailViewController = myVC;
[splitViewController layoutSubviews];
```

This avoids the wasteful overhead of removing the master viewcontroller's view and then resetting it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

No it isn't the right way,instead allocate your master and detail viewcontroller in navigationcontroller like
`UINavigationController *nav1 = [UINavigationController alloc]initwithrootviewcontroller:masterviewcontroller];`
likewise nav2 for detail.Then write

```
splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2, nil];
splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
```

Thats it.
Hope that helps.